# QGraphicsView subclass and events

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview

In my project I have a `QGraphicsView` and a `QGraphicsScene`. I need to add some extra events to my view so I've subclassed `QGraphicsView`.

The problem is that when I set a `mousePressEvent` I override the drag mode `ScrollHandDrag`.

My question is the following: is there a way to switch between the default `QGraphicsView` answer to `mousePressEvent` and a custom one (using the `m_click` to differentiate the different cases for instance)?

Here is my code:

*MyQGraphicsView.h*

```
class MyQGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    MyQGraphicsView(QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent = 0);

    public slots:
    // void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e);

    private:
    QGraphicsScene *m_scene;
    int m_click;
};
```

*MyQGraphicsView.cpp*

```
MyQGraphicsView::MyQGraphicsView(QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent) :
    QGraphicsView(parent),
    m_scene(scene),
    m_click(0)
{
    setScene(m_scene);
}

/*void MyQGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    double rad = 1;
    QPointF pt = mapToScene(e->pos());
    if (m_click)
    {
        m_scene->addEllipse(pt.x()-rad, pt.y()-rad, rad*2.0, rad*2.0, QPen(), QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
        m_click = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        m_click = 1;
    }
}*/
```

Basically what I would like the code to do is: when `m_click=1`, draw a point, but when `m_click=0` use the `ScrollHandDrag`.

I can make both work separately but not at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( !m_click ) {
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(e);
}
```

Just call the parent class' implementation to use the 'normal' behaviour.